# Magento 2.2.4: Module Manager not showing

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard, component-manager, magento2.2.4

I have updated to Magento 2.2.4 from 2.2.3

Now the Module Manager module grid is not showing:

[image]

Google Chrome console shows

> /setup/index.php/moduleGrid/modules:1 
>       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Microsoft Internet Explorer debugger shows

> [image]

Does anyone know what may be causing this? Everything worked fine in 2.2.3.

Comment: i think the version you are using is unstable and ver 2.2.3 was stable

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: Literally just ran into the very same problem after updating to 2.2.4. Will report back if I find something useful (or work it out)

Comment: Thanks @Craig , I'll also post if I find a solution. :)

Comment: Looks like this has been reported. Possible bug from latest update? Not sure: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15192

Comment: FYI: The github issue I mentioned now references a workaround, but I'd wait until next update unless you really NEED to get access to Web Setup Wizard Modules right away.

Comment: Many thanks for the update @Craig . Thanks also for posting some great videos, they've been a huge help :D

Comment: :) No problem, @Trevor

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have updated to Magento from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4 and now I am not able to open Module Manager. I have tried to replace line 181 at:
setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Grid/Module.php but it did not help. Any other idea why this happend ? Many thanks,
Nikola

Comment: I did this fix and after this Extension manager,Module manager,System Upgrade gives a blank site.
When i see at system configuration private key is missing and it doesnt being saved after input.
I restored from backup file but the problem remain.
..cache flush
..cache clean
But Same Problem.
Any suggestion ?
Thanks I get this error /setup/index.php/marketplace/check-auth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134853)

Answer (score 5):

```
setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Grid/Module.php

line 181
```

replace with

```
$item['moduleName'] = isset($item['moduleName']) ? $item['moduleName'] : $this->packageInfo->getModuleName($item['name']);
```

Always save copy of original file

Then refresh page (Module MANAGER) and should be working

Comment: +1 Thank you. I can confirm that this answer works. I upgraded from **Mag 2.2.2** to **Mag 2.2.5** and `Module Manager` showed a blank page exactly like the question's Screen Shot.  I just tried this solution. I edited the file as mentioned in line 181 and my `Module Manager` loads correctly now.

Comment: It works on my 2.2.5 as well!