# Magento 2.3.0: Module Manager not showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

I have updated to Magento 2.3.0

Now the Module Manager module grid is not showing:

**Expected result**

It should open and let me display all modules that are currently installed.

**Actual result**

URL encounters 404 http://storeurl/setup/index.php/moduleGrid/modules

[image]

Can you check anyone and let me know, how to fix these issues.

Comment: you can try reload.

Comment: @MichaelHa, can you send me the command?

Comment: it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225708/magento-2-2-4-module-manager-not-showing

Comment: @MichaelHa, yes i'm reviewd and the mention solution not working in my website